# computed function ignores if else statement

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have this computed function to filter my products, but it seems it just ignoring if else statement and when I move the return statement underneath the if else statement the if else statement is working but the return statement is not.

Here is the code :

```
computed: {
                filteredProducts: function() {

                    return this.products.filter((product) => {
                        return product.productName.toLowerCase().includes(this.keyword.toLowerCase());
                    });

                    var vm = this;
                    var category = vm.selectedCategory;

                    if(category.includes("All")) {
                        return vm.products;
                    } else {
                        return vm.products.filter((product) => {
                            var keys = Object.keys(product);
                            var matchFilter = false;
                            category.forEach((key) => {
                                if(product[key] === true) {
                                    matchFilter = true;
                                }
                            });
                            return matchFilter;
                        });             
                    }

                },

            },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

return exits the function straight away, it has no possibility of executing anything after the return.

So, for your code... your if elses return inside each of their clauses, and your return statement returns.   Nothing happens after the returns in your code.

So if you haven't really finished doing all the things you want to do, don't return, perhaps store the results in a variable, do the rest of what you need to do, then return the variable.

I'm not 100% of what you are intending, but it might look something like the following...

```
filteredProducts: function() {

    let filtered = this.products.filter((product) => {
        return product.productName.toLowerCase().includes(this.keyword.toLowerCase());
    });

    var vm = this;
    var category = vm.selectedCategory;

    if(category.includes("All")) {
        return filtered;
    } else {
        return filtered.filter((product) => {
            var keys = Object.keys(product);
            var matchFilter = false;
            category.forEach((key) => {
                if(product[key] === true) {
                    matchFilter = true;
                }
            });
            return matchFilter;
        });             
    }
},
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the reply, would you mind to give me a sample code for that?

Comment: not really sure what you are trying to achieve, but I've given an example where all the filter stuff can be used to limit the results